# SCIP and Visual Studio: error LNK2001

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, scip

I am trying to make the SCIP work with C++ in Windows 10. 
I want to solve the VRP problem using SCIP (version 3.2.1) in Visual Studio 2010.

I have downloaded Source files and then precompiled dlls from the http://scip.zib.de and included the .hpp and cpp files in my VS project.
there was a .dll, a .exe and a .lib file in the archive.

In the project properties I did the following:

C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories:
C:\scipoptsuite-3.2.1\scip-3.2.1\src\

C/C++ -> Linker -> Input-> Additional Dependencies:  C:\Users\Mahla\Desktop\src\scip-3.2.1.win.x86_64.msvc.opt.spx.ld.lib;

C/C++ -> General -> Input-> Additional Library Dependencies: 
C:\Users\Mahla\Desktop\src\scip-3.2.1.win.x86_64.msvc.opt.spx.ld.lib;

VC++ Directories-> Include Directories:
C:\Users\Mahla\Desktop\src;

VC++ Directories-> Library Directories:
C:\Users\Mahla\Desktop\src;

src folder is a copy of src down in the scip root directory.

I copied  .dll, .lib and .exe in the Debug folder at the same level as the solution .sln file in Visual Studio.

When building, I get  many errors like :

main_vrp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SCIPcreateConsLinear

Can anyone tell me what is the problem or how to set up an example in VS.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could investigate the libraries with this tool to find out where it is expecting its dependencies: http://www.dependencywalker.com

Comment: @mattmilten : I haved linked Cplex to the project and also installed scipoptsuite using Cygwin, so I think soplex should have been linked to the SCIP at default. Do I need to link SCIP and Cplex too, for building solution in visual studio?

Comment: The dll you downloaded contains SoPlex already. You also cannot link CPLEX to it since you can have only one LP solver at a time. The library should work on its own

Comment: Do I need to link .o and .a files in the lib and obj folder in SCIP root directory?

Comment: No, these are contained in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a x64 version of SCIP. So my  "Platform" should be x64, not Win32, or it will give LNK errors.
I simply changed the platform in configuration manager to x64 and everything was okay then.